# Uploading screenshots to Flickr

Tags: web-development, website-design, images

I have finally decided to create my own portfolio to show off my works for clients. I've seen on countless web design agency websites where they show screenshots of the websites they made for their clients. And a lot of them upload the shots to Flickr, and use the Flickr api to display the screenshots on their own website.

Is this OK to do?

Comment: Is there any benefit to hosting on Flickr over your own site? (Apart from possibly bandwidth.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a specific terms of service for the API, but it says on the [API home page](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/)

> The Flickr API is available for non-commercial use by outside
>   developers. Commercial use is possible by prior arrangement.

So technically, no.

Comment: That's strange. Practically everybody uses it for commercial use lol.

Answer (score 1):

For all practical purpose, they don't seem to really care.
If you embed a Flickr image on your site, you're expected to link back to the Flickr page for it, either via the image itself or a credit caption of some sort. But I've also never heard of them going after anyone who didn't follow through with this.